# Cómo coger únicamente los primeros elementos de un JSON

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, npm

Estoy intentando coger de un JSON ([este](https://www.mapabase.es/arcgis/rest/services/Otros/Gasolineras/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=json)) los precios de gasolina, pero hay casi mil precios distintos. A mí me interesa coger únicamente los 20 primeros (por ejemplo). Los precios de gasolina que necesito coger están dentro del apartado "features" y en cada objeto de "attributes". Este es el programa que tengo ahora mismo:

```
import React from 'react';
import { FlatList, ActivityIndicator, Text, View  } from 'react-native';

var sumaGas = 0;
var count = 0;


export default class FetchExample extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={ isLoading: true}
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        return fetch('https://www.mapabase.es/arcgis/rest/services/Otros/Gasolineras/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=json')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {

                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    dataSource: responseJson.features,
                }, function(){

                });

            })
            .catch((error) =>{
                console.error(error);
            });
    }



    render(){

        if(this.state.isLoading){
            return(
                <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 20}}>
                    <ActivityIndicator/>
                </View>
            )
        }
        return(
            <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop:20}}>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.attributes.precio_gasolina_95}</Text>}
                    keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }

}
```

El problema que tiene es que coge absolutamente todos los elementos del JSON y no quiero que lo haga. A mí me gustaría que cogiese los 20 primeros "precio_gasolina_95"
 **¿Hay alguna manera de que solo me seleccione los x primeros?**

Muchas gracias

Comment: Tienes dos opciones o seleccionas los 20 primeros o controlas desde el backend la cantidad de elementos que devuelves

Comment: @solamente ya, el problema es que no sé cómo hacer ninguna de esas dos cosas. Acabo de empezar con JS y no tengo ni idea

Comment: Prueba de recorrer el objeto responseJson y si tienes algún problema plantealo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pudes usar `.slice(inicio,fin)` y un `.map()` si solo quieres una parte del objeto:

```js
fetch('https://www.mapabase.es/arcgis/rest/services/Otros/Gasolineras/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=json')
  .then(response=>response.json())
  .then(myJson=>{    
  
    const primeros20 = myJson.features.
    slice(0,20).
    map(e=>e.attributes.precio_gasóleo_a);
    
    console.log(primeros20);
  });
```

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, muchas gracias